# Cannot read property 'tapAsync' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to serve my project with **vuetify** but I've got  `Cannot read property 'tapAsync' of undefined`.
I used Vue3 and Webpack4 :

main file:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";
// import { loadFonts } from "./plugins/webfontloader";

// loadFonts();

createApp(App).use(router).use(store).use(vuetify).mount("#app");
```

and in vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: ["vuetify"],

};
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "5.9.55",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.1",
    "roboto-fontface": "*",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-material": "^1.0.0-beta-15",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuetify": "^3.0.0-alpha.0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0",
    "webfontloader": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.0.0"
  }
```

Comment: You didn't show your dev deps. Do not use webpack dep. If you use Vue CLI, it already contains Webpack. The error seems to be caused by the conflict of webpack versions

Comment: have you installed Vuetify via vue cli? It seems that Vuetify 3 (which is an early alpha) creates this problem, I'm experiencing it too, not sure what to do about it yet (even how to fall back to no Vuetify as I added it with `vue add vuetify` – I'm considering using Bootstrap instead until they get this fixed).

Comment: You'll help community if you expand your question with all the necessary bits to reproduce and the error log. For me, the first line is `at <root>\front\node_modules\@vue\cli-plugin-pwa\lib\HtmlPwaPlugin.js:62:63` (although PWA didn't break things before adding Vuetify) and the rest of the lines tell about `<root>\front\node_modules\webpack\...`. Seems related: [similar issue](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/1377) with another webpack plugin, a [vue-clie issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1331) (closed) about no-html build

Answer (score 1):

upgrade Vue version

vue upgrade